# Get value of data-timestamp attribute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension, I'm trying to get info from a page (the value of "data-timestamp": 1490893300813) via a content script, but the result shows 'null'.

```js
//content script:

  var tsx = document.getElementsByClassName("date");    
  var i;
  const ts = new Array;
  for (i = 0; i < tsx.length; i++) {
    var ts[i] = tsx[i].getAttribute("data-timestamp");         
    console.log("Timestamp" + i + ": " + ts[i]);
  }
```

```html
<!--source code from page:-->

<div class="thread">
        <span data-timestamp="1490893300813" class="date">
            <span class="absolute">Do, 30.03.2017, 19:01</span>
            <span class="relative"></span>
        </span>
</div>
```

I also noticed that the data-timestamp attribute is visible when I show source-code of the page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) but it isn't visible in DevTools...

Comment: I don't see how your title relates to your question.

Comment: i changed that thx

Comment: `data` attributes are easily accessible through [`element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Comment: I moved your code into a snippet, as it was pure JavaScript/HTML and did not rely on any Chrome specific APIs. However, doing so makes it clear that there is an error in your code.  Is this the code you are actually using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySelector('.date')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the element that has the `date` class. From there, you can get the [`element.dataset.timestamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to get the timestamp.

Your code could look something like:

```js
//Get the timestamp as a number ( + is used to convert from a string to a number).
var timestamp = +document.querySelector('.date').dataset.timestamp;
console.log('Timestamp:', timestamp);

//Convert to a Date and display in ISO format for the UTC timezone.
var date = new Date(timestamp);
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

```html
<div class="thread">
        <span data-timestamp="1490893300813" class="date">
            <span class="absolute">Do, 30.03.2017, 19:01</span>
            <span class="relative"></span>
        </span>
</div>
```